# MySQL Editor Hangs on attempt to Launch on fresh Install

Tags: mysql

I have just downloaded the latest community installer (5.5.27) along with the workbench (5.2.41).
 
I clicked ok on all default settings on setup.

When I try to "Open a connection to start querying" on the workbench home page and chose "Local Instance MySql 55" I keep stuck on a never-ending "Opening SQL Editor" screen ("An SQL Editor instance for "Local Instance MySql 55" i s opening and should be available in a moment")

Any idea on what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what happened. I launched a command window, it worked.
 Then I retried, after clearing the password vault, and it worked.

Comment: @CallumKerr Weird (and sad) that this is still an issue 8 years later :)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too.
When you sign-in, just make sure that you've clicked the option "Add password to Keychain Access"

Answer (score 0):

I was trying

Database -> Connect to Database that result in closing the Workbench

[image]

Instead

[image]

That Solved the problem for me. I did clear the vault.

Comment: The "main-part" of your answer doesn't really make a difference.
The significant part - clearing the vault - is a side comment.
Maybe emphasize that part a bit more. (But that would be plagiarism, as the accepted answer tells you exactly that).